# How to display count of values based on other column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with below data

```
SQL> select * from mate2;

      A_CD       S_ID       E_CD S_E   S_NE  E_IND
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ----- -
       100          1          3 A     J     Y
       100          1          3 B     A     N
       100          1          3 A     D

       200          2          3 A     C     Y
       200          2          3 D     C

       300          3          3 B     N     Y
       300          3          3 N     N
```

I need to get count of distinct S_E,S_NE group by A_CD and (S_E, S_NE) as letter codes with below conditions:

1. take the value of S_NE when (E_CD = 3 AND E_IND = N)
2. take the value of S_E when E_CD = 3 AND E_IND = Y
3. take the value of S_NE when E_CD = 3 AND E_IND is null AND DISPLAY E_IND as N
4. take the value of S_E when E_CD = 3 AND E_IND is null AND DISPLAY E_IND as Y

The output should be like below. L_C is count of S_E,S_NE

```
A_CD L_C COUNT E_IND
---- --- ----- -----
100   A    3    Y
100   D    1    N

200   A    1    Y
200   D    1    Y
200   C    1    N

300   B    1    Y
300   N    1    Y
300   N    1    N
```

Sample table creation and data is below for testing

```
create table Mate2(a_cd number(5),S_ID NUMBER, E_CD number(10), S_E varchar2(5), S_NE varchar2(5), E_IND CHAR(1 byte));


insert into Mate2 values (100,1,3,'A','J','Y');
insert into Mate2 values (100,1,3,'B','A','N');
insert into Mate2(a_cd,S_ID,E_CD,S_E,S_NE) values (100,1,3,'A','D');
insert into Mate2 values (200,2,3,'A','C','Y');
insert into Mate2(a_cd,S_ID,E_CD,S_E,S_NE) values (200,2,3,'D','C');
insert into Mate2 values (300,3,3,'B','N','Y');
insert into Mate2(a_cd,S_ID,E_CD,S_E,S_NE) values (300,3,3,'N','N');
```

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? Post your code.

Comment: how did you get total L_C 4 for `A_CD 100` and 3 for `A_CD 200` and 3 for `A_CD` 300?

Comment: and what is the condition difference between 3 and 4?

Comment: We will count the values of S_E when E_IND is Y and S_NE when E_IND is N . And both separately when E_IND is null. In this case for a_cd 100 and E_IND is Y then we take value of S_E and get  A -1 and E_IND is N then we take the value of S_NE which is A and when E_IND is null we take both S_E and S_NE (A and D)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is what you are looking for, seems like you total number of records does not match the desired output you gave, otherwise try below:

```
SELECT ABC.a_cd,ABC.L_C,COUNT(*)as COUNT,ABC.E_IND FROM (
select A_CD, case when E_CD = 3 and E_IND  = 'N' then S_NE
                  when E_CD = 3 and E_IND = 'Y' then S_E 
                  when E_CD = 3 and E_IND is null then S_NE
                  when E_CD = 3 and E_IND is null then S_E
                  end as L_C,

             case when E_CD = 3 and E_IND is null then 'N'
                  when E_CD = 3 and E_IND is not null then 'Y'
                  else E_IND 
                  end as E_IND

FROM Mate2) as ABC
GROUP BY ABC.a_cd, ABC.L_C,ABC.E_IND
```

Comment: And I assume `is not null` in your 4th condition stead of`is null`, which will cause the conflicts when comparing to 3th condition

Comment: The requirement is pretty clear, and the OP meant `is null` as written. He wants to "fork" the rows where `e_ind` is `null`, essentially to count those rows twice, once "as if" `e_ind` was `'Y'` and the other "as if" it was `'N'`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to split `E_IND` first, then it gets simple

```
WITH data1 as (
    SELECT A_CD, E_CD, S_E, S_NE,
           CASE when E_CD = 3 and E_IND is null then 'N'
                else E_IND 
           END as E_IND
    FROM mate2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT A_CD, E_CD, S_E, S_NE, 'Y' E_IND
    FROM mate2
    WHERE E_CD = 3 and E_IND is null
)
SELECT A_CD, L_C, COUNT(*) as COUNT, E_IND FROM (
    SELECT A_CD,
           CASE when E_CD = 3 and E_IND = 'N' then S_NE
                when E_CD = 3 and E_IND = 'Y' then S_E
                else 'what_to_do_with_these'
           END as L_C,
           E_IND
    FROM data1
)
GROUP BY A_CD, L_C, E_IND
order by A_CD, E_IND desc, L_C;
```

I added one additional record with `E_CD = 2` to show a situation where no instruction was given for. I guess there is such data in your environment as the condition includes `E_CD`

```
insert into Mate2(a_cd,S_ID,E_CD,S_E,S_NE) values (100,1,2,'X','F');
```

The output is

```
A_CD    L_C COUNT   E_IND
----    --- -----   -----
100 what_to_do_with_these   1    - 
100     A   2       Y
100     A   1       N
100     D   1       N
200     A   1       Y
200     D   1       Y
200     C   1       N
300     B   1       Y
300     N   1       Y
300     N   1       N
```

Following your rules, the given result row `100   A    3    Y` was not correct, as one `A` comes from `E_IND = N`